# .htaccess for rewrite tool to chnage url for SEO

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently i have a url like this.

`http://domain.com/main.php?page=Welcome.php`

I'm looking to use the rewrite tool within `htaccess` to get rid of the `main.php?page=` so it will just become `http://domain.com/Welcome.php`

Or even better get rid of the `.php` to `http://domain.com/Welcome`

I have been trying to use the rewrite and using;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?Page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ main.php?Page=$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, i have added this to the root file the URLS have not chnaged.

Comment: Its okay ive fixed it :)